# super in the Ruby class

Tags: ruby

As I know 'super' calls the method of parent class.  Here is a code from jekyll project:

```
def read_yaml(base, name)
  super(base, name)
  self.extracted_excerpt = extract_excerpt
end
```

And here is a class declaration:

```
class Post
```

There is no parent class. What is the 'super' on this context ?

Here is [full class code](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/post.rb).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`super` doesn't just call methods on the parent class but also those in included modules.

The general resolution order is

- instance methods of the eigenclass (or singleton class, which is an alternative name for the same thing) of the object
- instance methods of the object
- methods in any included modules, starting from the last included module
- if not yet found, do all previous steps for the parent class (and then up until a method is found)

In this case, its [`Convertible#read_yaml`](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/4ca3fe513788220d56f21cd270c5aa8405d5a886/lib/jekyll/convertible.rb#L44-L59).

Comment: The official term is [singleton class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-singleton_class).

Comment: Both terms are official.

Answer (score 3):

Including a module adds it as an ancestor of the class, allowing its methods to be called with `super`. `Post` includes both `Comparable` and `Convertible`, so the super method is in one of those classes.

For example:

```
module Foo; end
class Bar
  include Foo
end

Bar.ancestors
# [Bar, Foo, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Answer (score -3):

In Ruby, the **super** keyword calls a parent method of the same name using the same arguments.

It can also be used for inherited classes.

**Example**

```
class Foo
  def baz(str)
    p 'parent with ' + str
  end
end
class Bar < Foo
  def baz(str)
    super
    p 'child with ' + str
  end
end

Bar.new.baz('test') # => 'parent with test' \ 'child with test'
```

Super can be called any number of times and can be used in multiple inherited classes.

```
class Foo
  def gazonk(str)
    p 'parent with ' + str
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
  def gazonk(str)
    super
    p 'child with ' + str
  end
end

class Baz < Bar
  def gazonk(str)
    super
    p 'grandchild with ' + str
  end
end

Baz.new.gazonk('test') # => 'parent with test' \ 'child with test' \ 'grandchild with test'
```

An exception will be raised if there is no **parent method** of the same name.

```
class Foo; end

class Bar < Foo
  def baz(str)
    super
    p 'child with ' + str
  end
end

Bar.new.baz('test') # => NoMethodError: super: no superclass method ‘baz’
```

Hope this helped.